# Python XML parsing and default NS

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am using xml.etree.ElementTree to parse an xml file. I was wondering if there's a way to set a default ns to be used for all the parsing operation.

Currently I use an approach like this snippet and it's ok:

```
name_space = 'myns'
if node.tag == '{%s}Name' % name_space:
```

Is there any better way when the ns is the same for all the tags?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NS_MAP = {"rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
        "rdfs": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#",
        "art": "http://simile.mit.edu/2003/10/ontologies/artstor#",
        "foaf": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/",
        "dcterms": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/",
        "sioc": "http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#",
         "oa": "http://www.openannotation.org/ns/"}
#short hands the ns
RDF = "{%s}" % NS_MAP['rdf']
RDFS = "{%s}" % NS_MAP['rdfs']
ART = "{%s}" % NS_MAP['art']
FOAF = "{%s}" % NS_MAP['foaf']
DCTERMS = "{%s}" % NS_MAP['dcterms']
SIOC = "{%s}" % NS_MAP['sioc']
OA = "{%s}" % NS_MAP['oa']
```

you can try something like this